# Parse JSON File and iterate over specific parameters

Tags: java, json, parsing, iteration

where I want to check which elements of the 1st file are missing in the second one.

Here is the form of the first one:

```
[
    {
        "pId": "pId1",
        "Platform":["ios","and","web","winph","win"],
        "Name": "ay",
        "ShortDescription": "Mobi",
        "Detail" : {
            "IncentiveInformation": "ppp",
            "DisplayName" : "vvv!",
            "Description" : "mmm",
            "TermsAndConditions": ".."
        }
    },
    {
        "pId": "pId2",
        "Platform":["afasd","sdfsd","pppp","asdas","win"],
        "Name": "ay",
        "ShortDescription": "mob",
        "PromotionDetail": {
            "DebugMode": false,
            "PromoDate": ["2015.01.01-00:01","2015.01.01-23:59"],
            "IncentiveInformation": "PRO",
            "Name": "iTunes",
            "ShortDescription": "Punkte sammeln bei iTunes",
            "DisplayName": null,
            "Description": null,
            "ImageURL": null,
            "JumpToShopURL": "urlHere",
            "JumpToShopName" : "Zu iTunes"
        }
    },
    {   
        "pId": "pId3",
        "Platform":["wqdsa"],
        "Name": "poti",
        "ShortDescription": "pun",
        "ImageURL": "url.here",
        "Promotion" : false,        
        "PromotionDetail": {
            "DebugMode": false,
            "PromoDate": ["2015.01.01-00:00","2015.01.01-23:59"],
            "IncentiveInformation": "ppeur",
            "Name": "namehere",
            "ShortDescription": "tune",
            "DisplayName": null,
            "Description": null,
            "ImageURL": null,
            "JumpToShopURL": "noq",
            "JumpToShopName" : "Zu"
        }
    }

]
```

and here is the form of the 2nd one:

```
    {
    "pList": [{
        "shortName": "bb",
        "longName": "bb",
        "pId": "pId2",
        "featured": true,
        "pLog": "url.here",
        "incentivation": "eu",
        "details": {
            "teaserImage": "image.url",
            "description": "desc here",
            "jumpToShopURL": "nurl",
            "jumpToShopButton": "zubay",
            "terms": [{
                "headline": "Wichtig",
                "body": "bodyline"
            }]
        }
    }, {
        "shortName": "one short name",
        "longName": "bkp",
        "pId": "pId1",
        "featured": true,
        "pLo": "some.pLo",
        "incentivation": "1p",
        "details": {
            "teaserImage": "some.url",
            "description": "desc",
            "jumpToShopURL": "short url",
            "jumpToShopButton": "Zuay",
            "terms": [{
                "headline": "Wichtig",
                "body": "bodyhere"
            }]
        }
    }]
}
```

Si I thought to save all the "pId" of the first one in a List(or array) and then iterate over that list and check for each one if the pId exists in the new one. 
So I tried this, but it is not working..

Could anyone help me with that? I tried a bit and then I found that I have too many difficulties, to get the pIds saved in a list or an array.

So has someone an idea?

```
import java.io.*;
import org.json.*;

public class MainDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {


        String jsonData = readFile("C:\\Users\\kbelkhiria\\Desktop\\Karim_JSON\\alt.json");
        JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(jsonData);
        JSONArray jarr = new JSONArray(jobj.getJSONArray("pList").toString());

        for(int i = 0; i < jarr.length(); i++) 
            System.out.println("id: " + jarr.getString(i)); 


    }

    public static String readFile(String filename) {
        String result = "";
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = br.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                line = br.readLine();
            }
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }


}
```

Comment: How do you know  if the element is in both lists? What should be the comparsion node?

Comment: pId is unique.. so pId should be the comparison node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the 2nd form, you have an JSONObject, but it contains some errors. Please fix them, or use a the 1st form again.

**SOLUTION**

I found some errors in the second file so I suggest the following edits:

- change `"jumpToShopURL": nurl",` to `"jumpToShopURL": null,`
- add a comma at the end of `"description": "desc"`
- add a comma at the end of `"jumpToShopURL": "short url"`

For the code, you can use the following lines:

```
    /*first file*/
    String jsonData = readFile("C:\\Users\\kbelkhiria\\Desktop\\Karim_JSON\\alt.json");
    JSONArray jarr =  new JSONArray(jsonData);

    /*array of first file's ids*/
    ArrayList<String> srcArray = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = 0; i < jarr.length(); i++) {
        srcArray.add(jarr.getJSONObject(i).getString("pId"));
    }

    /*second file*/

    // second form in a seperate file
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(readFile("C:\\Users\\kbelkhiria\\Desktop\\Karim_JSON\\alt2.json"));
    JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("pList");

    /*array of second file's ids*/
    ArrayList<String> dstArray = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
        dstArray.add(jarr.getJSONObject(i).getString("pId"));
    }

    for (String string : srcArray) {
        if (dstArray.indexOf(string)==-1)
            System.out.println(string + " is missing in the second file");
    }
```

Comment: So the solution above can run perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Luckily for you there are already developed libraries to parse any JSON string, like the one's you provided. One of the most popular is
[org.json](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java)

Using this you can write code similar to this:

```
import org.json.*;

String myString = ".." // The String representation you provided
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(myString);
JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("pList");
```

Another popular library for the same task is [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson)

Comment: can you tell me what exception it is? unfortunately i cant compile myself at the moment but it might me something simple. By the way i used the wrong variable name for the array, check my edit.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution using Jackson is the following:

```
private static final String JSON1 = // first json;

private static final String JSON2 = //second json;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    List<LinkedHashMap> list1 = Arrays.asList(mapper.readValue(JSON1, LinkedHashMap[].class));
    List<LinkedHashMap> list2 = Arrays.asList(mapper.readValue(mapper.readTree(JSON2).get("pList").toString(), LinkedHashMap[].class));
    List<LinkedHashMap> missingItens = new ArrayList<>();
    for (LinkedHashMap o1 : list1) {
        if (!objectExistsInList(o1.get("pId").toString(), list2)) {
            missingItens.add(o1);
        }
    }
}

private static boolean objectExistsInList(String pIdValue, List<LinkedHashMap> objs) {
    for (LinkedHashMap map : objs) {
        if (map.containsValue(pIdValue)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Please keep in mind this is a very specific implementation to the given JSONs.